# Big error with wrong \' and \" of code's surrounding

Tags: php, html, dictionary

I'm creating a interactive map of china and I need to use it in several pages, so I created a variable in php which contains the code but there are a lot of ' and " which cuts the code's surrounding, I already have this problem with the US map without adding \ for each ', can you help me or tell me what I have to do to solve this ? here's the code :

```
    $zhmap = '<map name="FPMap0" id="FPMap0">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;香港特別行政區 (Hong Kong)&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="557, 561, 560, 561, 563, 560, 565, 560, 565, 567, 560, 568, 556, 568, 554, 566, 555, 562, 556, 562">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;海南省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="492, 643, 488, 641, 481, 641, 475, 633, 473, 625, 485, 616, 485, 612, 507, 607, 512, 608, 513, 615, 506, 624, 506, 630, 492, 642">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;台湾&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="662, 499, 656, 504, 650, 513, 648, 523, 645, 533, 647, 541, 652, 547, 657, 552, 658, 558, 663, 559, 661, 551, 664, 544, 668, 537, 667, 526, 667, 509, 669, 502, 668, 500, 663, 500">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;河南省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="526, 334, 526, 345, 517, 353, 509, 354, 485, 366, 495, 384, 508, 399, 525, 399, 532, 401, 558, 411, 565, 402, 563, 394, 550, 389, 554, 383, 555, 376, 558, 368, 565, 371, 571, 367, 555, 358, 544, 351, 556, 336, 548, 334">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Shanxi&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="484, 370, 483, 369, 487, 353, 483, 345, 483, 337, 483, 329, 485, 325, 485, 316, 482, 311, 486, 303, 489, 288, 497, 283, 501, 275, 504, 272, 508, 273, 511, 269, 516, 270, 522, 266, 523, 262, 531, 282, 520, 300, 528, 314, 523, 330, 526, 336, 525, 348, 509, 354, 484, 371">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Ningxia Hui&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="406, 324, 421, 313, 421, 304, 429, 293, 432, 292, 435, 299, 430, 310, 438, 311, 443, 316, 441, 328, 435, 327, 431, 341, 437, 346, 432, 353, 429, 359, 423, 354, 417, 351, 417, 343, 414, 334, 408, 328">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Liaoning&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="585, 223, 583, 228, 587, 241, 582, 249, 590, 254, 596, 261, 608, 247, 616, 244, 624, 250, 615, 266, 620, 270, 616, 280, 639, 256, 648, 255, 665, 236, 664, 230, 656, 216, 647, 201, 633, 198, 629, 208, 621, 212, 595, 233">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;山东省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="549, 325, 554, 316, 566, 303, 575, 297, 587, 295, 591, 307, 597, 311, 607, 305, 615, 298, 624, 300, 637, 298, 637, 305, 631, 306, 617, 320, 610, 323, 602, 341, 597, 344, 594, 350, 593, 355, 586, 352, 580, 355, 570, 350, 565, 356, 555, 357, 547, 352, 556, 335, 552, 334">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;江西省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="543, 455, 547, 448, 551, 447, 565, 436, 568, 438, 579, 431, 579, 437, 581, 440, 587, 436, 588, 433, 596, 437, 602, 437, 600, 443, 609, 455, 599, 464, 595, 463, 592, 467, 591, 475, 585, 482, 584, 493, 581, 501, 579, 511, 579, 519, 577, 523, 573, 520, 559, 527, 556, 523, 561, 515, 558, 510, 552, 515, 549, 508, 553, 503, 548, 496, 547, 491, 545, 484, 540, 480, 549, 465, 543, 458">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Sichuan&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="311, 400, 319, 410, 328, 423, 325, 428, 329, 434, 330, 468, 333, 475, 341, 470, 346, 473, 344, 477, 353, 481, 368, 510, 377, 507, 383, 508, 387, 501, 384, 493, 393, 482, 393, 477, 399, 474, 398, 468, 405, 470, 406, 478, 410, 481, 417, 477, 421, 481, 434, 481, 432, 476, 425, 472, 430, 466, 434, 469, 430, 463, 424, 460, 419, 454, 426, 447, 424, 440, 427, 436, 435, 440, 442, 438, 447, 440, 451, 432, 452, 423, 462, 414, 459, 409, 458, 407, 450, 405, 440, 399, 431, 402, 423, 398, 417, 403, 408, 401, 404, 395, 403, 392, 399, 394, 388, 383, 388, 378, 375, 382, 378, 388, 376, 395, 369, 396, 363, 392, 354, 403, 342, 393, 337, 395, 331, 391, 314, 391, 311, 399">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;甘肃&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="304, 234, 300, 245, 291, 246, 265, 262, 267, 286, 280, 291, 287, 292, 296, 298, 307, 294, 323, 293, 337, 301, 345, 299, 355, 310, 364, 317, 369, 315, 379, 331, 386, 345, 380, 355, 376, 362, 370, 373, 368, 377, 359, 372, 359, 379, 367, 380, 372, 385, 375, 378, 385, 375, 399, 392, 402, 389, 409, 401, 417, 402, 426, 394, 423, 388, 432, 386, 431, 379, 434, 374, 432, 370, 432, 363, 440, 363, 449, 362, 449, 357, 458, 357, 461, 350, 456, 346, 459, 339, 441, 330, 432, 339, 437, 347, 433, 351, 429, 358, 419, 352, 413, 334, 405, 325, 396, 321, 393, 309, 398, 306, 400, 298, 393, 291, 383, 295, 374, 300, 364, 299, 354, 289, 345, 284, 346, 279, 352, 274, 350, 268, 337, 266, 327, 272, 318, 259, 316, 246, 315, 238, 304, 233">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;广西壮族自治区&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="409, 533, 409, 536, 414, 537, 421, 542, 433, 543, 434, 549, 425, 558, 429, 562, 440, 562, 445, 564, 444, 575, 452, 581, 460, 583, 468, 585, 473, 580, 482, 585, 490, 583, 496, 575, 500, 575, 500, 571, 505, 568, 504, 566, 515, 554, 514, 547, 520, 538, 523, 530, 521, 526, 515, 526, 512, 522, 510, 520, 507, 523, 507, 519, 511, 516, 510, 509, 510, 508, 508, 506, 507, 500, 501, 502, 494, 508, 490, 504, 487, 509, 482, 507, 469, 519, 466, 517, 459, 524, 449, 518, 438, 527, 435, 528, 431, 533, 419, 528, 410, 537">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;内蒙古自治区 (Өвөр Монгол)&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="534, 107, 530, 134, 524, 136, 527, 144, 531, 144, 538, 141, 544, 142, 546, 143, 553, 135, 562, 137, 577, 151, 576, 155, 565, 155, 555, 160, 548, 165, 539, 169, 537, 178, 528, 183, 522, 184, 508, 197, 499, 196, 494, 194, 490, 194, 483, 206, 492, 216, 476, 231, 461, 241, 443, 243, 437, 242, 425, 246, 408, 257, 403, 256, 401, 253, 389, 252, 374, 247, 368, 242, 350, 239, 329, 240, 315, 238, 317, 259, 327, 271, 334, 267, 350, 269, 353, 274, 347, 280, 346, 286, 354, 291, 363, 300, 373, 301, 388, 291, 396, 292, 400, 299, 399, 306, 394, 312, 397, 322, 406, 322, 419, 314, 420, 301, 430, 292, 433, 292, 436, 301, 432, 310, 437, 311, 443, 315, 448, 317, 455, 319, 468, 304, 477, 289, 481, 290, 485, 285, 489, 287, 493, 283, 497, 283, 501, 274, 503, 271, 508, 272, 511, 269, 516, 269, 521, 265, 519, 258, 520, 248, 525, 239, 530, 239, 534, 247, 545, 240, 550, 238, 554, 235, 554, 228, 562, 226, 570, 235, 575, 243, 584, 243, 584, 234, 581, 228, 586, 225, 594, 232, 600, 226, 610, 219, 618, 213, 626, 211, 633, 201, 628, 199, 629, 193, 621, 184, 614, 189, 609, 181">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;内蒙古自治区 (Өвөр Монгол)&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="607, 174, 609, 171, 600, 163, 601, 159, 607, 159, 612, 161, 612, 153, 613, 148, 618, 144, 612, 144, 604, 138, 605, 130, 619, 112, 623, 117, 625, 101, 627, 95, 625, 84, 629, 74, 631, 67, 619, 58, 612, 65, 603, 68, 596, 67, 592, 59, 592, 52, 585, 51, 582, 54, 575, 51, 579, 42, 575, 38, 566, 42, 561, 50, 565, 52, 571, 57, 568, 65, 563, 78, 558, 93, 561, 97, 549, 109, 540, 108, 532, 104, 532, 110, 531, 116">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;福建省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="600, 538, 597, 526, 591, 520, 589, 522, 586, 518, 580, 518, 581, 503, 584, 499, 586, 491, 585, 484, 592, 478, 592, 469, 596, 465, 599, 466, 609, 456, 612, 458, 615, 462, 618, 469, 622, 469, 627, 465, 631, 470, 635, 468, 640, 469, 637, 475, 634, 481, 629, 480, 632, 484, 632, 490, 632, 491, 633, 501, 628, 502, 626, 508, 622, 510, 620, 516, 612, 519, 614, 526, 601, 538">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;安徽省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="573, 436, 566, 422, 568, 418, 558, 413, 565, 404, 563, 394, 560, 396, 551, 390, 555, 383, 558, 371, 564, 374, 570, 370, 569, 363, 561, 359, 567, 358, 577, 365, 581, 365, 586, 370, 592, 370, 589, 376, 595, 384, 598, 384, 603, 381, 606, 383, 604, 386, 600, 387, 600, 393, 598, 396, 605, 403, 605, 407, 617, 409, 618, 414, 613, 419, 617, 420, 609, 422, 609, 430, 603, 438, 595, 438, 589, 434, 584, 435, 580, 431, 574, 437">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;上海&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="648, 397, 642, 397, 637, 407, 643, 411, 649, 409, 654, 404, 651, 400, 644, 399">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Yunnan&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="357, 582, 350, 590, 342, 589, 339, 578, 328, 577, 332, 561, 324, 560, 320, 548, 324, 544, 319, 542, 311, 542, 307, 545, 305, 544, 306, 538, 303, 535, 323, 506, 322, 492, 322, 488, 315, 481, 316, 475, 322, 474, 322, 463, 328, 458, 330, 472, 332, 477, 342, 470, 344, 474, 342, 480, 351, 481, 367, 510, 378, 508, 384, 509, 388, 503, 385, 493, 393, 483, 393, 478, 396, 476, 400, 474, 399, 471, 404, 471, 407, 479, 410, 482, 417, 479, 419, 485, 418, 488, 408, 490, 404, 488, 400, 489, 397, 492, 397, 498, 398, 503, 401, 504, 404, 502, 408, 502, 410, 506, 405, 516, 413, 525, 409, 538, 416, 541, 422, 545, 433, 547, 433, 553, 424, 559, 419, 559, 413, 565, 407, 570, 403, 566, 401, 572, 397, 568, 395, 570, 392, 568, 388, 574, 380, 568, 373, 574, 364, 576, 367, 585, 368, 592, 364, 596, 357, 587">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;广东省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="541, 574, 540, 570, 541, 561, 546, 568, 552, 559, 557, 558, 550, 563, 557, 559, 566, 555, 546, 565, 550, 563, 563, 557, 569, 555, 574, 554, 579, 556, 580, 552, 583, 556, 589, 550, 593, 551, 593, 547, 600, 539, 598, 529, 592, 523, 588, 524, 586, 521, 579, 520, 577, 524, 573, 522, 558, 530, 556, 525, 560, 516, 558, 513, 552, 517, 549, 513, 546, 516, 544, 517, 539, 514, 535, 518, 535, 523, 530, 520, 525, 521, 521, 528, 522, 530, 522, 535, 514, 550, 515, 558, 505, 569, 500, 575, 495, 580, 493, 588, 491, 592, 492, 601, 496, 607, 502, 603, 502, 600, 500, 594, 503, 591, 510, 583, 515, 582, 519, 582, 523, 578, 532, 576, 538, 575">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Xinjiang Uyghur&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="305, 236, 299, 227, 291, 209, 270, 196, 251, 193, 239, 186, 240, 181, 244, 176, 244, 161, 240, 151, 240, 146, 230, 139, 226, 141, 221, 136, 219, 131, 216, 129, 215, 122, 216, 119, 205, 118, 199, 126, 190, 128, 187, 134, 187, 146, 181, 149, 177, 153, 157, 142, 144, 166, 145, 170, 143, 176, 135, 171, 125, 173, 113, 173, 119, 176, 117, 196, 117, 203, 107, 209, 106, 219, 97, 221, 87, 224, 78, 229, 71, 230, 63, 227, 51, 237, 46, 233, 43, 229, 41, 231, 37, 228, 32, 232, 23, 232, 22, 240, 15, 244, 15, 248, 16, 254, 21, 256, 27, 262">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Xinjiang Uyghur&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="25, 266, 25, 275, 26, 279, 24, 281, 16, 281, 15, 283, 24, 286, 31, 295, 31, 301, 29, 304, 44, 318, 51, 319, 54, 321, 54, 330, 61, 339, 69, 339, 71, 341, 76, 335, 76, 331, 86, 326, 94, 328, 101, 332, 110, 325, 120, 328, 129, 334, 147, 332, 155, 333, 167, 327, 183, 324, 191, 326, 204, 333, 214, 332, 227, 332, 224, 324, 230, 319, 221, 308, 220, 296, 268, 288, 266, 261, 285, 250, 300, 245, 303, 238, 302, 237, 304, 235, 26, 262">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Xizang&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;BR&gt;&nbsp;(Tibet)&nbsp;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="308, 402, 297, 418, 282, 415, 270, 402, 253, 401, 245, 397, 238, 398, 232, 393, 216, 388, 202, 363, 204, 359, 206, 356, 211, 339, 197, 331, 184, 325, 176, 329, 165, 327, 153, 337, 146, 333, 139, 337, 129, 338, 117, 328, 111, 326, 102, 335, 86, 326, 78, 333, 75, 338, 68, 347, 60, 343, 57, 354, 63, 360, 65, 360, 63, 369, 54, 371, 52, 367, 47, 369, 51, 376, 50, 380, 49, 384, 50, 388, 52, 387, 72, 409, 76, 413, 76, 416, 84, 411, 106, 432, 109, 439, 113, 435, 117, 439, 115, 442, 124, 449, 126, 449, 128, 454, 133, 455, 144, 464, 150, 462, 157, 467, 162, 468, 167, 469, 178, 467, 181, 469, 179, 474, 178, 476, 191, 467, 200, 466, 206, 471, 212, 472, 216, 472, 221, 473, 221, 476, 231, 477, 243, 466, 247, 464, 252, 464, 263, 457, 275, 461, 286, 455, 291, 459, 287, 464, 294, 465, 290, 471, 301, 474, 305, 474, 308, 470, 315, 475, 320, 475, 322, 466, 328, 460, 329, 437, 326, 427, 328, 425, 320, 415, 316, 408, 310, 403">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;黑龙江省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="731, 86, 715, 100, 701, 108, 698, 110, 693, 105, 694, 100, 687, 94, 674, 88, 662, 86, 656, 88, 648, 80, 645, 73, 631, 50, 618, 34, 612, 33, 608, 39, 596, 30, 577, 39, 580, 44, 575, 52, 580, 56, 586, 52, 591, 53, 594, 66, 599, 68, 608, 69, 614, 66, 621, 60, 631, 71, 628, 78, 626, 85, 628, 97, 623, 108, 624, 121, 620, 115, 606, 132, 605, 139, 614, 144, 618, 143, 619, 144, 613, 155, 617, 151, 624, 150, 627, 154, 632, 162, 641, 162, 647, 159, 651, 164, 658, 162, 666, 164, 665, 168, 673, 169, 678, 178, 682, 175, 678, 168, 681, 166, 685, 172, 688, 178, 693, 182, 696, 177, 704, 171, 707, 171, 713, 176, 719, 177, 717, 167, 710, 156, 715, 152, 720, 145, 724, 146, 734, 144, 734, 128, 736, 123, 734, 105, 740, 98, 734, 89">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Jilin&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="695, 217, 690, 212, 701, 207, 703, 202, 708, 198, 708, 189, 712, 189, 715, 192, 721, 185, 720, 180, 716, 180, 706, 174, 701, 177, 694, 185, 688, 179, 683, 170, 681, 169, 683, 176, 679, 182, 674, 173, 667, 170, 665, 166, 658, 165, 652, 167, 649, 161, 644, 165, 634, 165, 626, 154, 617, 155, 613, 164, 610, 162, 602, 162, 604, 165, 609, 174, 610, 183, 614, 187, 616, 189, 623, 186, 629, 195, 631, 201, 638, 199, 642, 204, 649, 204, 653, 212, 659, 219, 662, 227, 666, 232, 667, 236, 675, 227, 674, 224, 678, 219, 682, 223, 693, 221">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;北京&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="564, 257, 558, 257, 554, 253, 550, 256, 550, 262, 547, 267, 541, 273, 540, 276, 552, 279, 553, 279, 559, 276, 560, 274, 557, 271, 563, 269, 565, 266, 565, 260">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;天津&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="571, 291, 567, 291, 563, 290, 560, 290, 559, 287, 561, 285, 560, 281, 558, 279, 559, 274, 563, 277, 564, 275, 565, 271, 565, 266, 569, 267, 569, 270, 568, 272, 570, 275, 574, 278, 575, 282, 573, 284, 573, 293">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Shaanxi&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="454, 321, 444, 318, 441, 328, 460, 342, 458, 349, 461, 354, 457, 360, 449, 360, 438, 363, 432, 365, 432, 373, 435, 371, 435, 376, 433, 382, 433, 388, 425, 391, 426, 396, 424, 399, 431, 405, 440, 402, 453, 410, 460, 408, 469, 413, 476, 416, 477, 410, 474, 401, 485, 400, 477, 395, 475, 390, 492, 392, 496, 389, 496, 387, 482, 371, 485, 355, 483, 348, 483, 332, 482, 327, 485, 323, 485, 317, 482, 311, 487, 304, 489, 289, 486, 287, 480, 293, 477, 293, 470, 304">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;湖北省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="464, 437, 464, 445, 474, 456, 477, 450, 484, 443, 488, 446, 493, 445, 494, 442, 492, 438, 508, 440, 518, 446, 528, 441, 527, 446, 536, 439, 541, 450, 565, 435, 570, 438, 572, 435, 566, 421, 567, 418, 552, 409, 543, 406, 537, 405, 526, 400, 510, 400, 498, 390, 491, 392, 480, 392, 485, 396, 484, 398, 476, 401, 478, 408, 486, 421, 485, 428, 475, 433, 465, 439">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;河北省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="554, 231, 554, 238, 548, 242, 540, 247, 534, 249, 531, 245, 530, 241, 525, 242, 520, 258, 527, 269, 531, 284, 521, 301, 529, 313, 523, 330, 534, 336, 549, 336, 547, 329, 552, 323, 557, 311, 566, 306, 573, 303, 574, 297, 567, 292, 559, 292, 559, 281, 552, 281, 543, 280, 540, 275, 548, 265, 553, 254, 558, 258, 565, 260, 565, 269, 559, 276, 561, 278, 563, 275, 566, 266, 569, 267, 575, 279, 577, 283, 582, 283, 589, 277, 588, 272, 597, 264, 591, 258, 583, 253, 585, 246, 576, 247, 562, 228, 555, 232">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;贵州省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="419, 482, 419, 490, 414, 491, 408, 492, 404, 490, 397, 494, 399, 502, 403, 502, 408, 502, 410, 505, 409, 511, 405, 518, 413, 527, 409, 535, 420, 528, 430, 534, 431, 530, 449, 519, 458, 524, 466, 518, 469, 521, 480, 508, 480, 503, 479, 495, 481, 494, 480, 491, 475, 490, 472, 493, 471, 490, 477, 485, 478, 483, 478, 479, 476, 470, 472, 474, 464, 467, 460, 462, 457, 464, 452, 460, 451, 460, 449, 465, 444, 465, 440, 469, 434, 471, 431, 468, 427, 471, 432, 476, 434, 482, 419, 483">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;浙江省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="637, 407, 635, 407, 632, 410, 625, 410, 622, 407, 618, 407, 619, 416, 614, 424, 610, 424, 610, 431, 601, 441, 601, 444, 609, 455, 614, 457, 617, 466, 618, 469, 623, 468, 627, 464, 631, 469, 636, 467, 639, 468, 643, 468, 644, 464, 643, 458, 646, 456, 654, 445, 654, 441, 661, 436, 661, 434, 658, 431, 658, 428, 659, 423, 661, 421, 661, 418, 658, 416, 652, 415, 647, 414, 640, 420, 635, 421, 635, 419, 641, 413, 639, 411">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;重庆&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="447, 442, 443, 439, 436, 441, 429, 436, 425, 441, 428, 447, 421, 454, 428, 458, 433, 463, 435, 468, 441, 467, 442, 462, 446, 461, 449, 464, 450, 455, 457, 458, 460, 456, 463, 458, 471, 471, 476, 466, 475, 457, 464, 446, 464, 439, 463, 436, 467, 433, 476, 432, 481, 427, 485, 426, 486, 419, 479, 411, 476, 418, 467, 412, 462, 409, 464, 413, 459, 418, 454, 422, 452, 434, 448, 444">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;江苏省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="619, 405, 628, 408, 637, 406, 638, 401, 645, 392, 638, 390, 646, 390, 638, 381, 630, 380, 628, 371, 616, 354, 608, 350, 605, 348, 602, 343, 594, 354, 583, 355, 571, 353, 569, 357, 585, 365, 591, 369, 592, 378, 598, 384, 606, 378, 607, 383, 600, 393, 604, 398, 608, 406">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;湖南省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="521, 525, 525, 519, 536, 519, 539, 511, 552, 512, 552, 503, 550, 486, 542, 478, 548, 466, 546, 449, 536, 440, 531, 443, 527, 443, 519, 446, 509, 440, 497, 441, 493, 446, 486, 443, 476, 455, 478, 467, 479, 482, 474, 491, 478, 491, 482, 505, 483, 507, 488, 507, 491, 503, 494, 506, 505, 500, 509, 507, 510, 515, 512, 518, 512, 521">
</map>
<img src="img/china.png" onclick="this.blur();" alt="Map of China" width="754" height="659" border="0" usemap="#FPMap0" class="imgBase" oncontextmenu="this.blur(); return false;">
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  var ol_bgcolor='#666666';
  var ol_textsize=2;
  var ol_wrap = 1;
  var ol_border = 2;
  //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chinamap.js"></script>';
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Use color syntax and check for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) would probably be the best solution in this case since it avoids the need to escape so many quotes.

```
<?php
$zhmap = <<<ZHMAP
<map name="FPMap0" id="FPMap0">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;香港特別行政區 (Hong Kong)&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="557, 561, 560, 561, 563, 560, 565, 560, 565, 567, 560, 568, 556, 568, 554, 566, 555, 562, 556, 562">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;海南省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="492, 643, 488, 641, 481, 641, 475, 633, 473, 625, 485, 616, 485, 612, 507, 607, 512, 608, 513, 615, 506, 624, 506, 630, 492, 642">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;台湾&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="662, 499, 656, 504, 650, 513, 648, 523, 645, 533, 647, 541, 652, 547, 657, 552, 658, 558, 663, 559, 661, 551, 664, 544, 668, 537, 667, 526, 667, 509, 669, 502, 668, 500, 663, 500">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;河南省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="526, 334, 526, 345, 517, 353, 509, 354, 485, 366, 495, 384, 508, 399, 525, 399, 532, 401, 558, 411, 565, 402, 563, 394, 550, 389, 554, 383, 555, 376, 558, 368, 565, 371, 571, 367, 555, 358, 544, 351, 556, 336, 548, 334">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Shanxi&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="484, 370, 483, 369, 487, 353, 483, 345, 483, 337, 483, 329, 485, 325, 485, 316, 482, 311, 486, 303, 489, 288, 497, 283, 501, 275, 504, 272, 508, 273, 511, 269, 516, 270, 522, 266, 523, 262, 531, 282, 520, 300, 528, 314, 523, 330, 526, 336, 525, 348, 509, 354, 484, 371">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Ningxia Hui&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="406, 324, 421, 313, 421, 304, 429, 293, 432, 292, 435, 299, 430, 310, 438, 311, 443, 316, 441, 328, 435, 327, 431, 341, 437, 346, 432, 353, 429, 359, 423, 354, 417, 351, 417, 343, 414, 334, 408, 328">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Liaoning&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="585, 223, 583, 228, 587, 241, 582, 249, 590, 254, 596, 261, 608, 247, 616, 244, 624, 250, 615, 266, 620, 270, 616, 280, 639, 256, 648, 255, 665, 236, 664, 230, 656, 216, 647, 201, 633, 198, 629, 208, 621, 212, 595, 233">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;山东省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="549, 325, 554, 316, 566, 303, 575, 297, 587, 295, 591, 307, 597, 311, 607, 305, 615, 298, 624, 300, 637, 298, 637, 305, 631, 306, 617, 320, 610, 323, 602, 341, 597, 344, 594, 350, 593, 355, 586, 352, 580, 355, 570, 350, 565, 356, 555, 357, 547, 352, 556, 335, 552, 334">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;江西省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="543, 455, 547, 448, 551, 447, 565, 436, 568, 438, 579, 431, 579, 437, 581, 440, 587, 436, 588, 433, 596, 437, 602, 437, 600, 443, 609, 455, 599, 464, 595, 463, 592, 467, 591, 475, 585, 482, 584, 493, 581, 501, 579, 511, 579, 519, 577, 523, 573, 520, 559, 527, 556, 523, 561, 515, 558, 510, 552, 515, 549, 508, 553, 503, 548, 496, 547, 491, 545, 484, 540, 480, 549, 465, 543, 458">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Sichuan&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="311, 400, 319, 410, 328, 423, 325, 428, 329, 434, 330, 468, 333, 475, 341, 470, 346, 473, 344, 477, 353, 481, 368, 510, 377, 507, 383, 508, 387, 501, 384, 493, 393, 482, 393, 477, 399, 474, 398, 468, 405, 470, 406, 478, 410, 481, 417, 477, 421, 481, 434, 481, 432, 476, 425, 472, 430, 466, 434, 469, 430, 463, 424, 460, 419, 454, 426, 447, 424, 440, 427, 436, 435, 440, 442, 438, 447, 440, 451, 432, 452, 423, 462, 414, 459, 409, 458, 407, 450, 405, 440, 399, 431, 402, 423, 398, 417, 403, 408, 401, 404, 395, 403, 392, 399, 394, 388, 383, 388, 378, 375, 382, 378, 388, 376, 395, 369, 396, 363, 392, 354, 403, 342, 393, 337, 395, 331, 391, 314, 391, 311, 399">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;甘肃&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="304, 234, 300, 245, 291, 246, 265, 262, 267, 286, 280, 291, 287, 292, 296, 298, 307, 294, 323, 293, 337, 301, 345, 299, 355, 310, 364, 317, 369, 315, 379, 331, 386, 345, 380, 355, 376, 362, 370, 373, 368, 377, 359, 372, 359, 379, 367, 380, 372, 385, 375, 378, 385, 375, 399, 392, 402, 389, 409, 401, 417, 402, 426, 394, 423, 388, 432, 386, 431, 379, 434, 374, 432, 370, 432, 363, 440, 363, 449, 362, 449, 357, 458, 357, 461, 350, 456, 346, 459, 339, 441, 330, 432, 339, 437, 347, 433, 351, 429, 358, 419, 352, 413, 334, 405, 325, 396, 321, 393, 309, 398, 306, 400, 298, 393, 291, 383, 295, 374, 300, 364, 299, 354, 289, 345, 284, 346, 279, 352, 274, 350, 268, 337, 266, 327, 272, 318, 259, 316, 246, 315, 238, 304, 233">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;广西壮族自治区&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="409, 533, 409, 536, 414, 537, 421, 542, 433, 543, 434, 549, 425, 558, 429, 562, 440, 562, 445, 564, 444, 575, 452, 581, 460, 583, 468, 585, 473, 580, 482, 585, 490, 583, 496, 575, 500, 575, 500, 571, 505, 568, 504, 566, 515, 554, 514, 547, 520, 538, 523, 530, 521, 526, 515, 526, 512, 522, 510, 520, 507, 523, 507, 519, 511, 516, 510, 509, 510, 508, 508, 506, 507, 500, 501, 502, 494, 508, 490, 504, 487, 509, 482, 507, 469, 519, 466, 517, 459, 524, 449, 518, 438, 527, 435, 528, 431, 533, 419, 528, 410, 537">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;内蒙古自治区 (Өвөр Монгол)&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="534, 107, 530, 134, 524, 136, 527, 144, 531, 144, 538, 141, 544, 142, 546, 143, 553, 135, 562, 137, 577, 151, 576, 155, 565, 155, 555, 160, 548, 165, 539, 169, 537, 178, 528, 183, 522, 184, 508, 197, 499, 196, 494, 194, 490, 194, 483, 206, 492, 216, 476, 231, 461, 241, 443, 243, 437, 242, 425, 246, 408, 257, 403, 256, 401, 253, 389, 252, 374, 247, 368, 242, 350, 239, 329, 240, 315, 238, 317, 259, 327, 271, 334, 267, 350, 269, 353, 274, 347, 280, 346, 286, 354, 291, 363, 300, 373, 301, 388, 291, 396, 292, 400, 299, 399, 306, 394, 312, 397, 322, 406, 322, 419, 314, 420, 301, 430, 292, 433, 292, 436, 301, 432, 310, 437, 311, 443, 315, 448, 317, 455, 319, 468, 304, 477, 289, 481, 290, 485, 285, 489, 287, 493, 283, 497, 283, 501, 274, 503, 271, 508, 272, 511, 269, 516, 269, 521, 265, 519, 258, 520, 248, 525, 239, 530, 239, 534, 247, 545, 240, 550, 238, 554, 235, 554, 228, 562, 226, 570, 235, 575, 243, 584, 243, 584, 234, 581, 228, 586, 225, 594, 232, 600, 226, 610, 219, 618, 213, 626, 211, 633, 201, 628, 199, 629, 193, 621, 184, 614, 189, 609, 181">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;内蒙古自治区 (Өвөр Монгол)&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="607, 174, 609, 171, 600, 163, 601, 159, 607, 159, 612, 161, 612, 153, 613, 148, 618, 144, 612, 144, 604, 138, 605, 130, 619, 112, 623, 117, 625, 101, 627, 95, 625, 84, 629, 74, 631, 67, 619, 58, 612, 65, 603, 68, 596, 67, 592, 59, 592, 52, 585, 51, 582, 54, 575, 51, 579, 42, 575, 38, 566, 42, 561, 50, 565, 52, 571, 57, 568, 65, 563, 78, 558, 93, 561, 97, 549, 109, 540, 108, 532, 104, 532, 110, 531, 116">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;福建省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="600, 538, 597, 526, 591, 520, 589, 522, 586, 518, 580, 518, 581, 503, 584, 499, 586, 491, 585, 484, 592, 478, 592, 469, 596, 465, 599, 466, 609, 456, 612, 458, 615, 462, 618, 469, 622, 469, 627, 465, 631, 470, 635, 468, 640, 469, 637, 475, 634, 481, 629, 480, 632, 484, 632, 490, 632, 491, 633, 501, 628, 502, 626, 508, 622, 510, 620, 516, 612, 519, 614, 526, 601, 538">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;安徽省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="573, 436, 566, 422, 568, 418, 558, 413, 565, 404, 563, 394, 560, 396, 551, 390, 555, 383, 558, 371, 564, 374, 570, 370, 569, 363, 561, 359, 567, 358, 577, 365, 581, 365, 586, 370, 592, 370, 589, 376, 595, 384, 598, 384, 603, 381, 606, 383, 604, 386, 600, 387, 600, 393, 598, 396, 605, 403, 605, 407, 617, 409, 618, 414, 613, 419, 617, 420, 609, 422, 609, 430, 603, 438, 595, 438, 589, 434, 584, 435, 580, 431, 574, 437">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;上海&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="648, 397, 642, 397, 637, 407, 643, 411, 649, 409, 654, 404, 651, 400, 644, 399">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Yunnan&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="357, 582, 350, 590, 342, 589, 339, 578, 328, 577, 332, 561, 324, 560, 320, 548, 324, 544, 319, 542, 311, 542, 307, 545, 305, 544, 306, 538, 303, 535, 323, 506, 322, 492, 322, 488, 315, 481, 316, 475, 322, 474, 322, 463, 328, 458, 330, 472, 332, 477, 342, 470, 344, 474, 342, 480, 351, 481, 367, 510, 378, 508, 384, 509, 388, 503, 385, 493, 393, 483, 393, 478, 396, 476, 400, 474, 399, 471, 404, 471, 407, 479, 410, 482, 417, 479, 419, 485, 418, 488, 408, 490, 404, 488, 400, 489, 397, 492, 397, 498, 398, 503, 401, 504, 404, 502, 408, 502, 410, 506, 405, 516, 413, 525, 409, 538, 416, 541, 422, 545, 433, 547, 433, 553, 424, 559, 419, 559, 413, 565, 407, 570, 403, 566, 401, 572, 397, 568, 395, 570, 392, 568, 388, 574, 380, 568, 373, 574, 364, 576, 367, 585, 368, 592, 364, 596, 357, 587">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;广东省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="541, 574, 540, 570, 541, 561, 546, 568, 552, 559, 557, 558, 550, 563, 557, 559, 566, 555, 546, 565, 550, 563, 563, 557, 569, 555, 574, 554, 579, 556, 580, 552, 583, 556, 589, 550, 593, 551, 593, 547, 600, 539, 598, 529, 592, 523, 588, 524, 586, 521, 579, 520, 577, 524, 573, 522, 558, 530, 556, 525, 560, 516, 558, 513, 552, 517, 549, 513, 546, 516, 544, 517, 539, 514, 535, 518, 535, 523, 530, 520, 525, 521, 521, 528, 522, 530, 522, 535, 514, 550, 515, 558, 505, 569, 500, 575, 495, 580, 493, 588, 491, 592, 492, 601, 496, 607, 502, 603, 502, 600, 500, 594, 503, 591, 510, 583, 515, 582, 519, 582, 523, 578, 532, 576, 538, 575">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Xinjiang Uyghur&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="305, 236, 299, 227, 291, 209, 270, 196, 251, 193, 239, 186, 240, 181, 244, 176, 244, 161, 240, 151, 240, 146, 230, 139, 226, 141, 221, 136, 219, 131, 216, 129, 215, 122, 216, 119, 205, 118, 199, 126, 190, 128, 187, 134, 187, 146, 181, 149, 177, 153, 157, 142, 144, 166, 145, 170, 143, 176, 135, 171, 125, 173, 113, 173, 119, 176, 117, 196, 117, 203, 107, 209, 106, 219, 97, 221, 87, 224, 78, 229, 71, 230, 63, 227, 51, 237, 46, 233, 43, 229, 41, 231, 37, 228, 32, 232, 23, 232, 22, 240, 15, 244, 15, 248, 16, 254, 21, 256, 27, 262">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Xinjiang Uyghur&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="25, 266, 25, 275, 26, 279, 24, 281, 16, 281, 15, 283, 24, 286, 31, 295, 31, 301, 29, 304, 44, 318, 51, 319, 54, 321, 54, 330, 61, 339, 69, 339, 71, 341, 76, 335, 76, 331, 86, 326, 94, 328, 101, 332, 110, 325, 120, 328, 129, 334, 147, 332, 155, 333, 167, 327, 183, 324, 191, 326, 204, 333, 214, 332, 227, 332, 224, 324, 230, 319, 221, 308, 220, 296, 268, 288, 266, 261, 285, 250, 300, 245, 303, 238, 302, 237, 304, 235, 26, 262">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Xizang&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;BR&gt;&nbsp;(Tibet)&nbsp;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="308, 402, 297, 418, 282, 415, 270, 402, 253, 401, 245, 397, 238, 398, 232, 393, 216, 388, 202, 363, 204, 359, 206, 356, 211, 339, 197, 331, 184, 325, 176, 329, 165, 327, 153, 337, 146, 333, 139, 337, 129, 338, 117, 328, 111, 326, 102, 335, 86, 326, 78, 333, 75, 338, 68, 347, 60, 343, 57, 354, 63, 360, 65, 360, 63, 369, 54, 371, 52, 367, 47, 369, 51, 376, 50, 380, 49, 384, 50, 388, 52, 387, 72, 409, 76, 413, 76, 416, 84, 411, 106, 432, 109, 439, 113, 435, 117, 439, 115, 442, 124, 449, 126, 449, 128, 454, 133, 455, 144, 464, 150, 462, 157, 467, 162, 468, 167, 469, 178, 467, 181, 469, 179, 474, 178, 476, 191, 467, 200, 466, 206, 471, 212, 472, 216, 472, 221, 473, 221, 476, 231, 477, 243, 466, 247, 464, 252, 464, 263, 457, 275, 461, 286, 455, 291, 459, 287, 464, 294, 465, 290, 471, 301, 474, 305, 474, 308, 470, 315, 475, 320, 475, 322, 466, 328, 460, 329, 437, 326, 427, 328, 425, 320, 415, 316, 408, 310, 403">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;黑龙江省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="731, 86, 715, 100, 701, 108, 698, 110, 693, 105, 694, 100, 687, 94, 674, 88, 662, 86, 656, 88, 648, 80, 645, 73, 631, 50, 618, 34, 612, 33, 608, 39, 596, 30, 577, 39, 580, 44, 575, 52, 580, 56, 586, 52, 591, 53, 594, 66, 599, 68, 608, 69, 614, 66, 621, 60, 631, 71, 628, 78, 626, 85, 628, 97, 623, 108, 624, 121, 620, 115, 606, 132, 605, 139, 614, 144, 618, 143, 619, 144, 613, 155, 617, 151, 624, 150, 627, 154, 632, 162, 641, 162, 647, 159, 651, 164, 658, 162, 666, 164, 665, 168, 673, 169, 678, 178, 682, 175, 678, 168, 681, 166, 685, 172, 688, 178, 693, 182, 696, 177, 704, 171, 707, 171, 713, 176, 719, 177, 717, 167, 710, 156, 715, 152, 720, 145, 724, 146, 734, 144, 734, 128, 736, 123, 734, 105, 740, 98, 734, 89">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Jilin&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="695, 217, 690, 212, 701, 207, 703, 202, 708, 198, 708, 189, 712, 189, 715, 192, 721, 185, 720, 180, 716, 180, 706, 174, 701, 177, 694, 185, 688, 179, 683, 170, 681, 169, 683, 176, 679, 182, 674, 173, 667, 170, 665, 166, 658, 165, 652, 167, 649, 161, 644, 165, 634, 165, 626, 154, 617, 155, 613, 164, 610, 162, 602, 162, 604, 165, 609, 174, 610, 183, 614, 187, 616, 189, 623, 186, 629, 195, 631, 201, 638, 199, 642, 204, 649, 204, 653, 212, 659, 219, 662, 227, 666, 232, 667, 236, 675, 227, 674, 224, 678, 219, 682, 223, 693, 221">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;北京&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="564, 257, 558, 257, 554, 253, 550, 256, 550, 262, 547, 267, 541, 273, 540, 276, 552, 279, 553, 279, 559, 276, 560, 274, 557, 271, 563, 269, 565, 266, 565, 260">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;天津&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="571, 291, 567, 291, 563, 290, 560, 290, 559, 287, 561, 285, 560, 281, 558, 279, 559, 274, 563, 277, 564, 275, 565, 271, 565, 266, 569, 267, 569, 270, 568, 272, 570, 275, 574, 278, 575, 282, 573, 284, 573, 293">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;Shaanxi&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="454, 321, 444, 318, 441, 328, 460, 342, 458, 349, 461, 354, 457, 360, 449, 360, 438, 363, 432, 365, 432, 373, 435, 371, 435, 376, 433, 382, 433, 388, 425, 391, 426, 396, 424, 399, 431, 405, 440, 402, 453, 410, 460, 408, 469, 413, 476, 416, 477, 410, 474, 401, 485, 400, 477, 395, 475, 390, 492, 392, 496, 389, 496, 387, 482, 371, 485, 355, 483, 348, 483, 332, 482, 327, 485, 323, 485, 317, 482, 311, 487, 304, 489, 289, 486, 287, 480, 293, 477, 293, 470, 304">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;湖北省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="464, 437, 464, 445, 474, 456, 477, 450, 484, 443, 488, 446, 493, 445, 494, 442, 492, 438, 508, 440, 518, 446, 528, 441, 527, 446, 536, 439, 541, 450, 565, 435, 570, 438, 572, 435, 566, 421, 567, 418, 552, 409, 543, 406, 537, 405, 526, 400, 510, 400, 498, 390, 491, 392, 480, 392, 485, 396, 484, 398, 476, 401, 478, 408, 486, 421, 485, 428, 475, 433, 465, 439">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;河北省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="554, 231, 554, 238, 548, 242, 540, 247, 534, 249, 531, 245, 530, 241, 525, 242, 520, 258, 527, 269, 531, 284, 521, 301, 529, 313, 523, 330, 534, 336, 549, 336, 547, 329, 552, 323, 557, 311, 566, 306, 573, 303, 574, 297, 567, 292, 559, 292, 559, 281, 552, 281, 543, 280, 540, 275, 548, 265, 553, 254, 558, 258, 565, 260, 565, 269, 559, 276, 561, 278, 563, 275, 566, 266, 569, 267, 575, 279, 577, 283, 582, 283, 589, 277, 588, 272, 597, 264, 591, 258, 583, 253, 585, 246, 576, 247, 562, 228, 555, 232">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;贵州省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCCCFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="419, 482, 419, 490, 414, 491, 408, 492, 404, 490, 397, 494, 399, 502, 403, 502, 408, 502, 410, 505, 409, 511, 405, 518, 413, 527, 409, 535, 420, 528, 430, 534, 431, 530, 449, 519, 458, 524, 466, 518, 469, 521, 480, 508, 480, 503, 479, 495, 481, 494, 480, 491, 475, 490, 472, 493, 471, 490, 477, 485, 478, 483, 478, 479, 476, 470, 472, 474, 464, 467, 460, 462, 457, 464, 452, 460, 451, 460, 449, 465, 444, 465, 440, 469, 434, 471, 431, 468, 427, 471, 432, 476, 434, 482, 419, 483">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;浙江省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="637, 407, 635, 407, 632, 410, 625, 410, 622, 407, 618, 407, 619, 416, 614, 424, 610, 424, 610, 431, 601, 441, 601, 444, 609, 455, 614, 457, 617, 466, 618, 469, 623, 468, 627, 464, 631, 469, 636, 467, 639, 468, 643, 468, 644, 464, 643, 458, 646, 456, 654, 445, 654, 441, 661, 436, 661, 434, 658, 431, 658, 428, 659, 423, 661, 421, 661, 418, 658, 416, 652, 415, 647, 414, 640, 420, 635, 421, 635, 419, 641, 413, 639, 411">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;重庆&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFCC');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="447, 442, 443, 439, 436, 441, 429, 436, 425, 441, 428, 447, 421, 454, 428, 458, 433, 463, 435, 468, 441, 467, 442, 462, 446, 461, 449, 464, 450, 455, 457, 458, 460, 456, 463, 458, 471, 471, 476, 466, 475, 457, 464, 446, 464, 439, 463, 436, 467, 433, 476, 432, 481, 427, 485, 426, 486, 419, 479, 411, 476, 418, 467, 412, 462, 409, 464, 413, 459, 418, 454, 422, 452, 434, 448, 444">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;江苏省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="619, 405, 628, 408, 637, 406, 638, 401, 645, 392, 638, 390, 646, 390, 638, 381, 630, 380, 628, 371, 616, 354, 608, 350, 605, 348, 602, 343, 594, 354, 583, 355, 571, 353, 569, 357, 585, 365, 591, 369, 592, 378, 598, 384, 606, 378, 607, 383, 600, 393, 604, 398, 608, 406">
<area href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;湖南省&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;', FGCOLOR, '#CCFFFF');" onmouseout="nd();" shape="poly" coords="521, 525, 525, 519, 536, 519, 539, 511, 552, 512, 552, 503, 550, 486, 542, 478, 548, 466, 546, 449, 536, 440, 531, 443, 527, 443, 519, 446, 509, 440, 497, 441, 493, 446, 486, 443, 476, 455, 478, 467, 479, 482, 474, 491, 478, 491, 482, 505, 483, 507, 488, 507, 491, 503, 494, 506, 505, 500, 509, 507, 510, 515, 512, 518, 512, 521">
</map>
<img src="img/china.png" onclick="this.blur();" alt="Map of China" width="754" height="659" border="0" usemap="#FPMap0" class="imgBase" oncontextmenu="this.blur(); return false;">
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  var ol_bgcolor='#666666';
  var ol_textsize=2;
  var ol_wrap = 1;
  var ol_border = 2;
  //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chinamap.js"></script>
ZHMAP;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just escape every single quote by adding a backslash.

Example:

```
onmouseover="return overlib(\'&lt;center&gt;&lt;B&gt;&nbsp;香港特別行政區 (Hong Kong)&nbsp;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/center&gt;\', FGCOLOR, \'#FFCCFF\');"
                            ^                                                                                    ^             ^        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

All your inner single quotes should have a backslash in front of them:

```
$var = ' "some" \'more text\' ';
```